# multiverse analysis in R: defining diff. poisson regressions with branch function does not work

Tags: r

I am trying to do a multiverse analysis where one of my specifications is different poisson regression models. I tryed many diff. codes, but it does not work. Can anybody help?

I tryed this code:

```
poisson_sex <- (branch(model_sex,
                        "poisson_sex" ~ glm(suicide_cases ~ sex + moonage_3days + sterbejahr, family = poisson(link = "log"), data = df.all_sex)
))
poisson_age_w <- (branch(model_age_w,
                        "poisson_age_w" ~ glm(suicide_cases ~ frauen_15_bis_49 + moonage_3days + sterbejahr, family = poisson(link = "log"), data = df.age_w)
))
poisson_dekade <- (branch(model_dekade,
                        "poisson_dekade" ~ glm(suicide_cases ~ dekade + moonage_3days + sterbejahr, family = poisson(link = "log"), data = df.dekade)
))
poisson_season <- (branch(model_season,
                           "poisson_season" ~ glm(suicide_cases ~ season + moonage_3days + sterbejahr, family = poisson(link="log"), data = df.season)
))
poisson_wohnbund <- (branch(model_wohnbund,
                          "poisson_wohnbund" ~ glm(suicide_cases ~ wohnbund + moonage_3days + sterbejahr, family = poisson(link="log"), data = df.wohnbund)
))
```